# Two-variable Wronskian; regularity of coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, wronskian

Let $f(x,y),g(x,y)$ be two real-analytic functions near a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$. Consider the following Wronskian determinant:
$$
D(x,y):=\det
\begin{bmatrix}
f(x,y) & g(x,y)\\
\partial_x f(x,y) & \partial_x g(x,y)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
If that $D(x,y)=0$ constantly, we know that for each $y$, $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent when viewed as functions of $x$. That means there are functions $\lambda(y)$ and $\mu(y)$, not simultaneously zero at any $y$, such that for every $(x,y)$ we have
$$
\lambda(y)f(x,y)+\mu(y)g(x,y)= 0.
$$
My question is:

1. Can we always normalise so that we may assume $\lambda(y)=\cos \theta(y)$ and $\mu(y)=\sin \theta(y)$?
2. Are $\lambda(y)$ and $\mu(y)$ smooth, or even real-analytic?

Comment: How did you came to the conclusion that The functions $\lambda$ and $\mu$ depend only on $y$ ? I think It could be $\lambda(x,y)$ and $\mu(x,y)$...

Comment: @AndreaS. Isn't it because f and g are linearly dependent as functions of x?